# find the maximum cost of removing all occurrences of substrings “he” and “lo”

Tags: python-3.x

For given string S and integers P and Q, which denotes the cost of removal of substrings “he” and “lo” respectively from S, the task is to find the maximum cost of removing all occurrences of substrings “he” and “lo”.

example if S = 'hellohellohellohellohello', P = 6, Q = 4, then cost to remove 'he' and 'lo' is 50

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Read [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 0):

There was no example for where the OP was stuck, but you can use the `re` module for this.

This works:

```py
import re

s = "hellohellohellohellohello"

x = re.findall('he', s)
y = re.findall('lo', s)

p = len(x) * 6
q = len(y) * 4

print(p+q)
```

result:

```
50
```